# NHibernateIntegrationFacility configuration

Tags: nhibernate

I am trying to use NHibernateIntegration Facility by configuring using code, not XML. But couldn't find any reference code over the web. Can you please post any sample or provide reference.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Fluent NHibernate API. I am developing using it a year ago and it is very good.
You can download the dll by NuGet in visual studio.

Link:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentNhibernate